# Swift cocoa pods issue "Use of unresolved identifier"

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I started faced with very often problem for me is:

```
Use of unresolved identifier ''
```

So I want to use this [library](https://github.com/kaishin/Gifu) in my Swift project, but seems my project does not see files.

when I try to use `AnimatableImageView` object I get `Use of unresolved identifier 'AnimatableImageView'`

Comment: Did you import the library into your class?

Comment: How did you import the library into your project?

Comment: @simpleBob oh seems I need to import module `import Gifu`

Comment: @Siriss `import Gifu` works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Edit your build settings and add "Other Linker Flags" = "-ObjC""

Else, use "import Gifu". this should work.

Comment: How do you determine `import Gifu` vs `import AnimatableImageView` or something else? – In other words, given the format is `import [LIBRARY_NAME]` how is `LIBRARY_NAME` determined? What is to proceed the term `import` ? Should it be the "name" value from the `.podspec` file? Should it be the "bundle name"?  How do you find this for some arbitrary pod?

Comment: @Snakeoil :
Gifu uses a UIImageView subclass and an animator that keeps track of frames and their durations.

It uses CADisplayLink to animate the view and only keeps a limited number of resized frames in-memory, which exponentially minimizes memory usage for large GIF files (+300 frames).
The documentation of Gifu oblige you to set "import Gifu" . It's not you that chooses . For Gifu for example, AnimatableImageView is just a class inside this library.

Comment: Thanks. So then what determines the text which goes immediately after `import`? Other than the documentation, how would you know what to import by simply looking at a pod?